# Flexbox with collapsible elements - prevent width changes

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

I am using the disclosure elements ( and ) inside a flexbox along with another element.
Is there anyway I can force the collapsed element (i.e. the ) to take up the same width as the expanded element?
Currently, when I expand the details, the width will increase, and then decrease when I collapse it again:
[image: expanding width behaviour]

This image shows the flexbox around the two elements:

[image]

I essentially want the collapsed width to be equal to the expanded width, preferably without setting any fixed widths....

Comment: It would be very helpful, if you share code snippet. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Personally I feel that the best way would be to set a width on the container of the accordion. However, since you do not want to explicitly set widths, here is something you could do.

Instead of hiding your collapsible item by using `display: none`, use `visibility: hidden` instead. This will render the element invisible and you will not be able to interact with it, but it will preserve the width needed for rendering, since the element is still there. To get rid of the vertical space, set `height: 0`.

I've created a snippet for you to look at:

```js
function  toggle(el) {
  el.children[0].classList.toggle('hide')
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.main {
  background: steelblue;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidepanel {
  background: crimson;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidepanel">
  <ul onclick="toggle(this)"> Click Me!
  <div class="hide">
  <li>Data</li>
  <li>Data</li>
  <li>Data that has some words</li>
  </div>
  </ul>
    
  </div>
  <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

There's an issue with this approach though. If you do not set a width on the left panel it might take up too much space, if the menu items do not wrap their text. And wrapping of text implies that there is some sort of defined width so...